# Java FX - Removing a node if the user unchecks a checkbox

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a GUI using JavaFx, I want a name field to appear if the check box is checked and disappear if it is not checked.

Here is the code I wrote

```
        test1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Boolean b = test1.isSelected();
            log(b);
            Label label1 = new Label("Name:");
            TextField textField = new TextField();
            HBox hb = new HBox();
            if (test1.isSelected()) {
                hb.getChildren().addAll(label1, textField);
                hb.setSpacing(10);
                grid.add(hb, 3, 3);
            } else {
                **hb.getChildren().removeAll(label1 , textField);** <---look at this!
            }

        }
    });
```

I am removing the node if it is unchecked but it doesn't execute it accordingly. What am I doing wrong?

Incase it is required, here is how I execute my scene.

```
Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 500, 500);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: The effect of your code is that when the user unchecks the check box, you create a brand new `HBox` and remove a brand new label and text field from it.

Comment: Thank you. You are pretty smart sir! I found my mistake. If you wish, you are welcome to post it as an answer so I can accept your answer as  it solved my problem

Comment: Wow , I feel I should have thought about it even further before posting it.